# Required attributes in XML serialization

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

For example I have class to serialize

```
[Serializable]
class Person
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I need to make Name attribute required. How to do this in .NET?

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly do you want to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `[Serializable]` is not used by the XML Serializer.

Second, there is no way to make it required.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the `XmlIgnoreAttribute` along with the `<FieldName>Specified` pattern to throw an exception if the property is left blank or null. During serialization the `NameSpecified` property will be checked to determine if the field should be rendered, so if the Name properties left null or empty an exception is thrown.

```
class Person
{
   [XmlElement("name")]
   string Name { get; set; }
   [XmlIgnore]
   bool NameSpecified
   {
      get { 
              if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) throw new AgrumentException(...);

              return true;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks very hacky. :/

Answer (score 6):

The best way to solve this is by having a separate XSD which you use to validate the XML before you pass it onto the `XmlSerializer`. The easiest way to work with XSD's and `XmlSerializer` is to start off with an XSD, [generate the code for the `XmlSerializer` from this XSD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) and [also use it to validate the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513024/getting-started-with-xsd-validation-with-net).

Comment: Woah! This looks very convoluted! Is this the official way? Could a code sample help here? (making it less "link only" vibe)

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
```

Comment: `Name` in question is an attribute + `XmlElementAttribute`'s default constructor already sets IsNullable to false

Comment: This annotation is for the element, not for the attribute

Answer (score -5):

I believe you are confusing XML with an XSD. If you want your property to always have a value, initialize this property in the constructor, and throw an exception if anyone tries to set it to empty or null.

```
class Person
{

  private string _Name = "Not Initialized";
  [XmlAttribute("name")]
  string Name {
    get { return _Name;}
    set {
        if(value == null || value==string.Empty) throw new ArgumentException(...);

        _Name = value;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: -1: The person class is not XML-serializable because it has no public parameterless constructor. Fix that and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: This will not work. Such constructor will never used with serialization, so the Name setter will not called too.

Comment: The Name attribute will not ever be set if omitted from the originating model. XmlSerializer does not enforce the required rule. Pieter Van Ginkel's response is the closest to accurate; however, has the required step of defining an XSD from the model (keeping it up to date) and requires customizations for string-based attributes, since they're nullable by nature.