# Deserialize XML with multiple values

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I was using this [Xml Deserialization with complex elements in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409954/xml-deserialization-with-complex-elements-in-c-sharp) as a reference. I've noticed there are a lot of threads about Deserializing xml, but they don't mention when a tag has multiple values within it.

I am trying to deserialize my xml for lvl3 into an array of objects.

I'm getting a "there is an error in the xml document (1, 2)" error.

I have an xml string that I'm retrieving via an HTTP GET request that is formatted like this:

```
<xml ...>
   <lvl1 id="xxx" name="yyy">
      <lvl2 id="aaa" name="bbb">
         <lvl3 id="mmm" name="nnn" val1="ppp" val2="qqq">
            <lvl4a x="000" y="000" z="000" />            
            <lvl4b a="000" b="000" c="000" />
            <lvl4c l="000" w="000" h="000" />
            ...
         </lvl3>
      </lvl2>
   </lvl1>
</xml>
```

I have the following code that keeps throwing an exception:

`"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll"`

The exception is thrown by this line:

`temp = (Test)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test)).Deserialize(rdr);`

But I'm not sure how to go about debugging it to find the error. Here is the complete code:

```
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

    XmlNodeList list = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("lvl2");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        Test temp = new Test();
        using (XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(list[i].InnerXml)))
        {
            temp = (Test)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test)).Deserialize(rdr); // exception thrown here
        }
        Console.WriteLine(temp.id);
        Console.WriteLine(temp.overall.x);
    }

    [XmlRoot("lvl3")]
    public class Test{
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "lvl4a")]
        public Overall overall { get;set; }
    }

    public class Overall
    {
        [XmlAttribute("x")]
        public string x { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("y")]
        public string y { get;set; }

        [XmlAttribute("z")]
        public string z { get;set; }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug and check where is the exception coming and if there is an inner exception?

Comment: I did, there was no inner exception

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either fix your `Test` class to include public properties for `val1` and `val2` attributes or remove them from the xml. The schema of xml should match the class structure.