# How to determine if XML has unclosed strings

Tags: c#, xml

I have many XML files and some of them might have unclosed strings like this

```
<ns0:Info InfoTyp="53" InfoID="/>
```

Those unclosed strings dont always appear as the last part of the tag

Is there a way in **Notepad++** or in **C#** to easily detect when a file has this kind of strings ?

How can I also detect other kind of error in the XML file that make it an invalid XML ? I need to try to parse it to detect this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C# you can try to load xml file into XDocument (or XmlDocument):

```
using System.Xml.Linq; // include this in your using directives

try
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
}
catch (XmlException e)
{
    // xml is invalid     
}
```

`XmlException` contains information about line number and position which caused error. Also exception message is pretty informative. E.g. for you xml it will say:

> Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not
>   closed:  Line 1, position 35.

Answer (score 0):

In c#

```
try
{
    XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(path);
}
catch(XmlException ex)
{
    //oops xml not formatted properly
}
```

---

In Notepad++

Check RegularExpression option

Find What: `\A([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)*\z`

If it matches you have a valid xml

Comment: Thanks...but the notepad regular expression needs to detect the INVALID ones

Comment: So I run the "Search in files" option and the list of results is the opposite of what I need ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia the regex would work for odd cases..not even..so don't use it

Answer (score 0):

You can validate against an XSD schema to ensure an XML document is well formed and conforms to a specific structure.

This is a good post to get you started if using .NET...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553468/1246574

Comment: You can generate one easily enough, even using Visual Studio, or an XML editor like Oxygen.

Comment: Validation is different than checking if a document is well-formed. Unclosed strings would indicate a document that wasn't well-formed and should even be allowed to be validated.